# Studying alternatives: integrate SCORM and LMS without frames

Tags: javascript, php, scorm

I would like to know more about SCORM.

Ive beeing studying [moodle module](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/master/mod/scorm) and the [SCORM.com documentation](https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/api-discovery-algorithms/) but im not arriving to an aproach myself. As far i can tell steps are:

- Upload to LMS a SCORM package
- Develop a player that contains some controlls to browse the package
- Provide a javascript API, called API for SCORM1.2 and API_1484_11 for SCORM2004. Implement then "at least" some basic calls to the API: Terminate, Commit, Intialize, etc. These functions will be called from the packet.
- On the player open the package using a frame. ¿Any alternative?

Ive done this all but im not able to make it work. Im just writing this to make sure these are the correct steps for an LMS-SCORM integration.

So, basically my situation is that by the point of view of an LMS, how to show the packet without frames, and how to retrieve data from packets using PHP and javascript.

Maybe im pretending too much but better thing would be to make all types of SCORM packets to work.

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the basic steps, but the devil is in the details. It isn't really enough to only implement '"at least" some basic calls' unless you are producing all of the content that you will play. This is because you can't really know which of the runtime API calls will be made by a given piece of content. Also note that SCORM2004 has a whole sequencing implementation that is needed in order for the course to display and load the proper SCOs, etc.

Generally you can't really implement SCORM without frames (iframes do work), short of popping up new windows for all content which isn't ideal. This is because there is a pre-defined search algorithm the content will be using to locate the SCORM JS API(s) and that algorithm is designed to walk the tree of windows in the browser to locate it. Without frames (or separate windows) this algorithm won't work.

As far as the data, the "packet" (or SCO) is communicating via the JS runtime API so the data is being provided to the player via those calls. It is up to the implementer to decide what to do with that data so that the LMS can make use of it.

Writing a SCORM implementation, particularly a 2004 one, is a non-trivial pursuit.

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for the answer and make me understand that i cant avoid using frames. You say here "the data is being provided to the player via those calls". Could u give me a reference to docs on this point? I haven't found anything on this topic. I know this isnt trivial, I've been doing some research and I barely found information...

Just for asking,  can [Experience API](https://experienceapi.com/) give me an aproach to SCORM integration or its just useful for TIN CAN? Thanks so much!

Comment: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/ is a concise doc about the RT for SCORM. https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/ provides more summary level info on SCORM handling in general. xAPI is a data model and communication protocol only, Tin Can (packages with a tincan.xml) are from a set of guidelines released with the 0.9 spec. Both are unrelated to SCORM other than they are effectively package, launch, and record of (typically) e-learning content. cmi5 is a more appropriate place to start on that path currently.